# Solaris 11.1 smb share pam.conf

Tags: network-share, server-message-block, solaris-11

I would like to enable an SMB share on Solaris 11.1 x64
My steps:

1. `pkg install service/filesystem/smb`
2. `svcadm enable -r smb/server`
3. `echo "other password required pam_smb_passwd.so.1 nowarn" >> /etc/pam.conf`
4. `useradd public`
5. `smbadm enable-user public`
6. `zfs set share=name=fs1,path=/rpool/fs1,prot=smb rpool/fs1`
7. `zfs set sharesmb=on rpool/fs1`
8. `passwd -r files public`

Step 8 failes: It is not possible to enter a password, output is:

> solaris> passwd -r files public
>
> Please try again
>
> Please try again
>   Permission denied

If I uncomment the new line in `pam.conf`, it is possible to change the password.
Nevertheless, it is not possible to access the share from Windows 7. The Solaris machine is reachable with ping.

Access with another SMB enabled user is denied too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit the same problem myself, reading the docs the PAM configuration has been split off into a directory and sub-files, like linux if your familiar with that?

To resolve the problem remove the line from the /etc/pam.conf file and add to the /etc/pam.d/other file as follows...

```
# echo "password required    pam_smb_passwd.so.1    nowarn" >> /etc/pam.d/other
```

You should then be able to set the password for 'public'

IMHO the Oracle documentation for Solaris 11 is way better than Sun ever produced, I found the answer on this page...

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29004/configuringoperationmodetm.html#configureworkgroupmodetask

Comment: I would suggest editing the files with an ***editor***, not `echo`ing stuff and appending it to the end of the file. With the technique you're suggesting there's no way to know what's in the file already, and you lose the ability to properly match formatting, whitespace, etc.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. And of course, i used an editor to add the line. Thx